# Wish to Circumambulate Around Mt. Kailash

Tags: shiva, karma, moksha

I wish to [circumambulate around Mount Kailash](http://www.sacred-destinations.com/tibet/mount-kailash) on foot. This is roughly 33 miles of mountaineous terrain.

Many people do this for spiritual reasons, i.e circumambulate once to wash away your sins, circumambulate 108 times to attain nirvana.

I just want to circumambulate around Mount Kailash because I want to.

What type of training do I require? I understand this can take years, even decades.

Some information about me.

- lady in mid-30s (people swear I am in early 20s)
- 5'4", 140lbs (last time I weighed myself was Jan 2016)
- mostly eat fruits, veggies, fiber
- exercise 4 to 5 days a week, perform [Surya Namaskar](http://www.skinsheen.com/userfiles/image/sun.jpg) (started with 3 reps in Summer 2015, I'm up to 69 reps now, goal to reach 108 reps by end of 2017), plus light weights

Comment: Website of [MEA- Kailash Manasarovar Yatra](http://kmy.gov.in/kmy/eligibility.do?lang=en_US) by Govt. of India  may help you. This site has every details you want.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Thank you for the link. It gives some idea. However, I am not citizen of India.

Comment: You can contact KMY-MEA to know about training and i think they will help you though you aren't from India.